# Unit Test Case for Angular + Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have to write unit test case for implementation of the following method in Jasmine.How do I trigger method2 from method1 where we are returning a function.

```
method1(data) {
  const returnData = {
    callBackMethod1 : (item) => this.method2(item),
    item: data 
  }
  return data;
}

method2(item){
  return item.parentId;
}
```

Comment: Where does item come from?

Comment: It could be instance of this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `spyOn` on `method2` then call `method1` and then expect `method2` to be called.

```
const data = {...};

spyOn(component, 'method2');

component.method1(data);

expect(component.method2).toHaveBeenCalled();
```